# Wordpress -- add description below to featured image

Tags: wordpress

I would like to add an annotation below featured image box in post page ,saying

'Recommended image size: 1300px (width) x 340px (height)

Is it possible in wordpress 4.2.2.

The text is for the admin user for a better guidance.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You should go to `wp-admin->includes->post.php`
and around line 1295 (depending on version) you will find:

```
if ( !empty( $thumbnail_html ) ) {
    $ajax_nonce = wp_create_nonce( 'set_post_thumbnail-' . $post->ID );
    $content = sprintf( $set_thumbnail_link, $upload_iframe_src, $thumbnail_html );
    $content .= '<p class="hide-if-no-js"><a href="#" id="remove-post-thumbnail" onclick="WPRemoveThumbnail(\'' . $ajax_nonce . '\');return false;">' . esc_html__( 'Remove featured image' ) . '</a></p>';
}
```

change it to:

```
if ( !empty( $thumbnail_html ) ) {
            $ajax_nonce = wp_create_nonce( 'set_post_thumbnail-' . $post->ID );
            $content = sprintf( $set_thumbnail_link, $upload_iframe_src, $thumbnail_html );
            $content .= '<p class="hide-if-no-js"><a href="#" id="remove-post-thumbnail" onclick="WPRemoveThumbnail(\'' . $ajax_nonce . '\');return false;">' . esc_html__( 'Remove featured image' ) . '</a><span style="display:block;">Recommended image size: 1300px (width) x 340px (height)</span></p>';
        }
```

It is not recommended to change core files as your changes can be lost during the update, but I don't recommend creating a plugin just for this small change.

Comment: Thank you so much..Yes it's a small change so better to edit the core file.

Comment: Better not to edit core files. 

Check this one: https://salferrarello.com/featured-image-label-wordpress/

Answer (score 3):

Old post here, but I was trying to do this as well. A filter since WordPress 2.9.0 offers this capacity, like so:

```
/**
 * Filters the admin post thumbnail HTML markup to return.
 *
 * @since 2.9.0
 * @since 3.5.0 Added the `$post_id` parameter.
 * @since 4.6.0 Added the `$thumbnail_id` parameter.
 *
 * @param string $content      Admin post thumbnail HTML markup.
 * @param int    $post_id      Post ID.
 * @param int    $thumbnail_id Thumbnail ID.
 */
return apply_filters( 'admin_post_thumbnail_html', $content, $post->ID, $thumbnail_id );
```

So use it like this:

```
function stackoverflow_30817906( $content, $post_id, $thumbnail_id ) {
    if ( 'post' !== get_post_type( $post_id ) ) {
        return $content;
    }
    $caption = '<p>' . esc_html__( 'Recommended image size: 1300px (width) x 340px (height)', 'i18n-tag' ) . '</p>';
    return $content . $caption;
}
add_filter( 'admin_post_thumbnail_html', 'stackoverflow_30817906', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Hi this code doesnt work in wordpress version 6. Do you have any reference ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this without editing core files you could just use jQuery to add the text.

```
add_action('admin_footer', function() {
    global $pagenow;
    if('post.php' == $pagenow || 'post-new.php' == $pagenow) : ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $('#postimagediv .inside').after('<div style="padding: 0 12px 12px;">Recommended image size: 1300px (width) x 340px (height)</div>');
        });
    </script>
<?php endif;
});
```

This solution isn't as 'clean' as making the change directly in the PHP file, but I think it is preferable to editing the core. With this solution you don't have to worry about remaking the change after a WordPress update.